# JavaScript window.print leave empty footer

Tags: javascript, css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Calculator and I am using Javascript window.print to save my results as PDF.

Although the first's page header is fine, and there is enough space

[image]

There is no space on the footer or the header on the rest of the pages

[image]

I found a few answers on CSS style referring to @media print but nothing works.

So basically, I want all pages to have header and footer space.

Comment: I would look into something like [JSReport](https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local), it can be sort of confusing at first but once you figure it out it is pretty nice, you can basically set up the configurations for how you want it to work such as what engine to use and what recipe, and then you just pass it an HTML string and it generates your PDF for you. If you want better control over the margins then there are ways of embedding margin data into your html string that gets used by JSReport and it looks pretty good. External Link tags aren't loaded, so write your own CSS locally.

Comment: I don't think that works with my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this on my CSS

```
@page {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    
}
```